# Regex to replace all occurences of a character within a given context

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I am trying to write a search and replace regex (in ruby) to replace all instances of a character in a string in a given context.

The regex needs to replace all instances of "." in a json key, and I'm battling with references. I have a feeling that I need to use a lookaround in some way, but the variations I've tried I can't seem to get working.

Some example strings:

```
, "key1.name" : " value.something "
, "key2.complex.name" : "value.else"
, "this.is.the.most.complex.name" : "value"
```

I initially had this regex to replace a single occurrence (replacing it with "FULLSTOP"):

```
s/, "([^.]+)\.([^"]+)" :/, "\1FULLSTOP\2" :/g‏‏
```

Desired output:

```
, "key1FULLSTOPname" : " value.something "
, "key2FULLSTOPcomplexFULLSTOPname" : "value.else"
, "thisFULLSTOPisFULLSTOPtheFULLSTOPmostFULLSTOPcomplexFULLSTOPname" : "value"
```

I'm guessing I need to use a `(?=\.)` somehow in the search, but not sure how to use this correctly with references. I am using the opening `,` and ending `:` as a way of defining the context for a json key.

thanks in advance.

Comment: replaces fullstops in the values too. I am updating my question to clarify that I only want to replace in the JSON key, not value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(?=.*?\:)\.
```

Use this.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/cH8vN2/5

Edit:

```
(?=.*?\"\s*\:)\.
```

Use this to be very sure.

See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/cH8vN2/6

Comment: that is great.  i knew i needed a lookahead for it. once i see it, it makes sense.

Comment: @Brett yes just dig into it to unravel the great power of regex.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following as a sample :

```
str = ', "this.is.the.most.complex.name" : "value';
str = str.gsub(/\.+/, 'FULLSTOP');

puts str;
```

I have not taken care of the 'value' part.

You should be able to do that easily.

Comment: the issue is that the JSON is all on 1 line, and has fullstops in the value as well, so it needs to be contextualized to keys.

Comment: You can do it in two steps then  :
Step 1 : Find out all the strings between ',' and ':'.
 You will get an array of all the JSON keys here
Step 2 : Apply the above logic on all these strings found